# Удалять посты через месяц

Tags: laravel5

У меня есть таблица БД с постами в проекте Ларавел, я хочу удалять все статьи, которые на сайте больше месяца, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам понадобится использовать Carbon. Вот готовый код, для вас:

```
use Carbon\Carbon; 
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller{

public function create(Request $request) { 

Post::where('created_at','<', Carbon::now()->addDays(-30))->delete();
 … }
}
```

Если помог, то примите ответ пожалуйста!)